# dynamic row values wrongly updated into mysql php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, foreach

Here i'm trying to edit & update my dynamic row values using php. This is my edit.php page coding. it fetch the dynamic row datas from mysql perfectly..

```
$uid = (int)$_GET['id'];
$tariff_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ebvouchertariffs WHERE VoucherID_Fk = $uid");
if(mysql_num_rows($tariff_query)>=1) {
    echo "<table>
    <tr>
    <td>SL.NO</td>
    <td>DATE</td>
    <td>PARTICULARS</td>
    <td>NO OF NIGHTS</td>
    <td>RATE</td>
    <td>PRICE</td>
    <td>TAX %</td>
    </tr>";
    while($t_row = mysql_fetch_array($tariff_query)) {
        echo "<tr>
            <td><input type=text name=slno[] value= ". $t_row['TariffSlNo'] ."></td>
            <td><input type=text value=". $t_row['TariffDate'] ." name=date[] id=SelectedDate onClick=GetDate(this); readonly=readonly/></td>
            <td><input type=text name=particulars[] placeholder=\"Description\" value=". $t_row['TariffParticulars'] ."></td>
            <td>";
        echo "<select name=noofnights[] value= >";
        echo "<option>" . $t_row['NoOfNights'] . "</option>";
        echo "<option></option>"; 
        echo "<option value=1>1</option>
              <option value=2>2</option>
              <!-- cutted -->
              <option value=20>20</option>";
        echo "</select>"; 
        echo "
            <input type=text onblur=\"this.value=addzeros(this.value)\" onKeyUp=\"return valtxt(this)\" name=rate[] value=". $t_row['TariffRate'] .">

            <input type=text name=price[] value=". $t_row['TariffPrice'] ." readonly=readonly>
            <input type=text name=tax[] onblur=\"this.value=addzeros(this.value)\" onKeyUp=\"return valtxt(this)\" value=". $t_row['TariffTax'] ." >
            <input type=hidden name=taxtotal[] readonly=readonly value= ></td>
        </tr>";
    }
}
```

This is my update.php page coding. it updates the datas wrongly.

**Before Update :**

[image]

**After Update :**

[image]

i edited all rows and columns and when i updated the voucher it always updates the last row values in all rows. you can see in that image. But i'm using edit and update option for single text field. it workings fine. Dynamic row values wrongly updated into database. for generate dynamic rows i'm using javascript... how to solve this problem?

```
include("config.php");
if(isset($_POST['submit_val'])) {
   $uid = (int)$_POST["edited"];
    foreach( $_POST['slno'] as $key=>$slno ) {
        $e_date = $_POST['date'][$key];
        $e_particulars = $_POST['particulars'][$key];
        $e_noofnights = $_POST['noofnights'][$key];
        $e_rate = $_POST['rate'][$key];
        $e_price = $_POST['price'][$key];
        $e_tax = $_POST['tax'][$key];
        $e_nettotal = $_POST['nettotal'];
        $e_totalamount = $_POST['totalamount'];
        $e_finaltotal = $_POST['finaltotal'];
        $e_slno = mysql_real_escape_string($slno);
        $e_date = mysql_real_escape_string($e_date);
        $e_particualrs = mysql_real_escape_string($e_particulars);
        $e_noofnights = mysql_real_escape_string($e_noofnights);
        $e_rate = mysql_real_escape_string($e_rate);
        $e_price = mysql_real_escape_string($e_price);
        $e_tax = mysql_real_escape_string($e_tax);
        $e_nettotal = mysql_real_escape_string($e_nettotal);
        $e_totalamount = mysql_real_escape_string($e_totalamount);
        $e_finaltotal = mysql_real_escape_string($e_finaltotal);
        $e_tariff = "UPDATE ebvouchertariffs SET TariffSlNo = '$e_slno', TariffDate = '$e_date', TariffParticulars = '$e_particulars', NoOfNights = '$e_noofnights', TariffRate = '$e_rate', TariffPrice = '$e_price', TariffTax = '$e_tax', TariffNetTotal = '$e_nettotal', TariffAddTotal = '$e_totalamount', TariffFinalTotal = '$e_finaltotal', ModifiedOn = NOW() WHERE VoucherID_Fk = '$uid'";
    }
    mysql_query($e_tariff)or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_close($link);
}
```

I posted another question here [Here is the link for another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20794722/mysql-wrongly-update-the-dynamic-row-records)

Comment: Where you set `$e_slno` ?

Comment: i didn't... i will change this  $e_slno = mysql_real_escape_string($e_slno); to  $e_slno = mysql_real_escape_string($slno); now..

Comment: Try execute your code now

Comment: no.. yet again same result..

Comment: Can you show print_r($_POST)? after `if(isset($_POST['submit_val'])) {`

Comment: after if(isset($_POST['submit_val'])) {  i have this one $uid = (int)$_POST["edited"]; for get edited values from another page..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have many rows with same `VoucherID_Fk` `UPDATE` set data for all this rows. You need have set `TariffSlNo` to WHERE condition

```
$e_tariff = "UPDATE ebvouchertariffs SET 
    TariffDate = '$e_date', 
    TariffParticulars = '$e_particulars', 
    NoOfNights = '$e_noofnights', 
    TariffRate = '$e_rate', 
    TariffPrice = '$e_price', 
    TariffTax = '$e_tax', 
    TariffNetTotal = '$e_nettotal', 
    TariffAddTotal = '$e_totalamount', 
    TariffFinalTotal = '$e_finaltotal', 
    ModifiedOn = NOW() 
WHERE
    TariffSlNo = '$e_slno' AND VoucherID_Fk = '$uid'";
```

Comment: yes thanks its working. silly mistake.. i forget to mention $e_slno.. but is there any possible way to insert a new row while updation. for example if user want to edit a voucher. in that voucher already contains 5 rows. user can edit their row values and if they want add two more rows.. i will try.. if you have any idea let me know.. Thanks again..

Comment: @Indian, not at wall, and Happy New Year!

Comment: @Indian, do you have unique ID for ebvouchertariffs ? Use it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not executing the sql query inside the for loop. when the loop get finished it returns the last query and then execute the last sql query using mysql_query which is outside the loop.

Solution:

Execute "mysql_query($e_tariff)or die(mysql_error());" inside the for loop so that the query will get execute every the loop runs.

Example:

```
include("config.php");
if (isset($_POST['submit_val'])) {
    for ($_POST['slno'] as $key=>$slno) {
        // ....
        // rest of the code
        $e_tariff = "UPDATE ebvouchertariffs SET TariffSlNo = '$e_slno', TariffDate = '$e_date', TariffParticulars = '$e_particulars', NoOfNights = '$e_noofnights', TariffRate = '$e_rate', TariffPrice = '$e_price', TariffTax = '$e_tax', TariffNetTotal = '$e_nettotal', TariffAddTotal = '$e_totalamount', TariffFinalTotal = '$e_finaltotal', ModifiedOn = NOW() WHERE VoucherID_Fk = '$uid'";
        mysql_query($e_tariff)or die(mysql_error());
    }
```

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: WHERE VoucherID_Fk = '$uid' Are you sure? you are updating each time to the same row id???

Comment: yeah same row id. i'm sure. because when i create a voucher those dynamic row values are stored into database perfectly. when i click edit button it fetch the dynamic row values corectly (sometimes 5 rows, 10 rows 2 rows). Updation is my problem

Answer (score 0):

try this code. I have commented where your error is and make it correct.

```
include("config.php");
if(isset($_POST['submit_val'])) {
   // $uid = (int)$_POST["edited"]; <-- this will get same id for all records there is no value for "edited" in $_POST so it will update all records.
   foreach( $_POST['slno'] as $key=>$slno ) {
        $uid = (int)$slno; // <-- Update it by slno this will work.
        $e_date = $_POST['date'][$key];
        $e_particulars = $_POST['particulars'][$key];
        $e_noofnights = $_POST['noofnights'][$key];
        $e_rate = $_POST['rate'][$key];
        $e_price = $_POST['price'][$key];
        $e_tax = $_POST['tax'][$key];
        $e_nettotal = $_POST['nettotal'];
        $e_totalamount = $_POST['totalamount'];
        $e_finaltotal = $_POST['finaltotal'];

        $e_slno = mysql_real_escape_string($slno); // <-- here you are doing mistake replace $e_slno by $slno

        $e_date = mysql_real_escape_string($e_date);
        $e_particualrs = mysql_real_escape_string($e_particulars);
        $e_noofnights = mysql_real_escape_string($e_noofnights);
        $e_rate = mysql_real_escape_string($e_rate);
        $e_price = mysql_real_escape_string($e_price);
        $e_tax = mysql_real_escape_string($e_tax);
        $e_nettotal = mysql_real_escape_string($e_nettotal);
        $e_totalamount = mysql_real_escape_string($e_totalamount);
        $e_finaltotal = mysql_real_escape_string($e_finaltotal);
        $e_tariff = "UPDATE ebvouchertariffs SET TariffSlNo = '$e_slno', TariffDate = '$e_date', TariffParticulars = '$e_particulars', NoOfNights = '$e_noofnights', TariffRate = '$e_rate', TariffPrice = '$e_price', TariffTax = '$e_tax', TariffNetTotal = '$e_nettotal', TariffAddTotal = '$e_totalamount', TariffFinalTotal = '$e_finaltotal', ModifiedOn = NOW() WHERE TariffSlNo = '$uid'";
    }
    mysql_query($e_tariff)or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_close($link);
}
```

Comment: no. if i removed this code **$uid = (int)$_POST["edited"];** it will not update. because i got edited values from another page using this code...

Comment: then you are doing wrong you are keeping same $uid = (int)$_POST["edited"]; for all rows as per your code. you need unique value for each row. You have to update record by $slno so you can have unique id for each row.

Comment: yes. your point makes me think. here my $uid is VoucherID_Fk. this is a reference key of another one. but your code doesn't work. i will try..

Comment: I have updated query you it should work. You can check it now.

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment: `for example if user want to edit a voucher. in that voucher already contains 5 rows. user can edit their row values and if they want add two more rows...` 
then try this.

first delete the old data and then insert new one.

```
$deletequery  = "delete from `ebvouchertariffs` WHERE VoucherID_Fk = '$uid' ";
```

and then  insert new data.

```
 foreach( $_POST['slno'] as $key=>$slno ) {
   $insertquery  = "insert into `ebvouchertariffs`.......";
 }
```