# Mysql wrongly update the dynamic row records

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, foreach

I trying to update my dynamic row values here. When i insert a new voucher record it could inserted the values correctly into database. When i edit the record values that time also it fetch the values from database correctly. But updation is my problem. It always update the last row values in all rows..

Previously i posted another question here related to this question but still didn't clear this error.  [Here is the link for another same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20628000/dynamic-row-values-wrongly-updated-into-mysql-php)

**Updation page PHP Coding :**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_val']))
    {
    $uid = (int)$_POST["edited"];
    foreach( $_POST['slno'] as $key=>$slno ) 
    {
        $e_date = $_POST['date'][$key];
        $e_particulars = $_POST['particulars'][$key];
        $e_noofnights = $_POST['noofnights'][$key];
        $e_rate = $_POST['rate'][$key];
        $e_price = $_POST['price'][$key];
        $e_tax = $_POST['tax'][$key];
        $e_nettotal = $_POST['nettotal'];
        $e_totalamount = $_POST['totalamount'];
        $e_finaltotal = $_POST['finaltotal'];

        $e_slno = mysql_real_escape_string($e_slno);
        $e_date = mysql_real_escape_string($e_date);
        $e_particualrs = mysql_real_escape_string($e_particulars);
        $e_noofnights = mysql_real_escape_string($e_noofnights);
        $e_rate = mysql_real_escape_string($e_rate);
        $e_price = mysql_real_escape_string($e_price);
        $e_tax = mysql_real_escape_string($e_tax);
        $e_nettotal = mysql_real_escape_string($e_nettotal);
        $e_totalamount = mysql_real_escape_string($e_totalamount);
        $e_finaltotal = mysql_real_escape_string($e_finaltotal);
        $e_tariff = mysql_query("UPDATE ebvouchertariffs SET TariffSlNo = '$e_slno', TariffDate = '$e_date', TariffParticulars = '$e_particulars', NoOfNights = '$e_noofnights', TariffRate = '$e_rate', TariffPrice = '$e_price', TariffTax = '$e_tax', TariffNetTotal = '$e_nettotal', TariffAddTotal = '$e_totalamount', TariffFinalTotal = '$e_finaltotal', ModifiedOn = NOW() WHERE VoucherID_Fk = '$uid'");
    }
mysql_close($link);
    }
```

I attached a few images here..

**Before Updation:**

[image]

**After Updation**

[image]

You can see above images here. When i update a row it always updates the last row values in all rows.. Where i made a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

because your where condition is wrong,

have a look at

`$e_tariff = mysql_query("UPDATE ebvouchertariffs SET TariffSlNo = '$e_slno', TariffDate = '$e_date', TariffParticulars = '$e_particulars', NoOfNights = '$e_noofnights', TariffRate = '$e_rate', TariffPrice = '$e_price', TariffTax = '$e_tax', TariffNetTotal = '$e_nettotal', TariffAddTotal = '$e_totalamount', TariffFinalTotal = '$e_finaltotal', ModifiedOn = NOW() WHERE VoucherID_Fk = '$uid'");`

the `$uid` pointing to wrong key, the key should come from inside of foreach

Comment: no its not working. same result..

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure about it. But as much as I hv come across php I hv never seen "Key" of a multi dimensional associative array as being used as second index parameter while displaying data from an array!!! I cant comment so i posted this as an answer... Sry. :)

Comment: i'm using javascript for generate dynamic rows. i want to edit my previous voucher values. sometimes user can edit the values sometime they add another couple of rows. so only i'm using this code for update the records.

Comment: yeah i got that!!! But just check if your syntax for displaying the values from array is correct.

Comment: syntax for display the values from array is absolutely correct. i'm sure. above i attached an image **Before Updation**. you can see some three different row values are there. that values also displaying the values from array correctly. if i once updated it will change the last row values in every rows.. i posted another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20628000/dynamic-row-values-wrongly-updated-into-mysql-php see this link. you can see my editpage php coding in that given link...

Comment: You might have tried this but though.. Put the update code after the foreach loop ends!!!! See if it works...